# How can you dump MySql database after each update?

Tags: mysql, import, revision-history

After I make a change to a database in MySql (Update, Delete, Insert, Create etc) is it possible to get MySql to dump the database or export the last run query to a sql file?

Comment: Could you explain what you need it for beyond what the query log gives you? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html

Comment: Are you looking for something like Binary Logging?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html  Its hard to be sure of your exact purpose as you've not been specific enough.

Comment: Query logging is what I am currently looking at and also Starx answer. I think I should be able to get what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is backing up every transactions on the db.

So, check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/backup-policy.html) page, and start using transactions on your query.